# if clause teminates the workflow in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

When I look at the following code, I think "CheckChoice(IntSelect)" will always execute no matter "if (isNaN(IntSelect))" will execute or not.

If I input a NaN and the CheckChoice function worked, the alert("The value supplied is out of range!"); should also display as the "default" branch. But it does not happen as I expected.

I do not understand what happens when input is a NaN, can anybody explain it please.

Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
   <title>Using the Default Clause</title>
   <script language="JavaScript">
      function CheckChoice(option)
      {
         // Make a selection.
         switch (option)
         {
            case 1:
               document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML =
                  "You chose Item A.";
               break;
            case 2:
               document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML =
                  "You chose Item B.";
               break;
            case 3:
               document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML =
                  "You chose Item C.";
               break;
            default:
               // Display an error dialog.
               alert("The value supplied is out of range!");
               break;
         }
      }

      function MakeAChoice()
      {
         // Ask the user to provide input.
         var Selection = prompt("Type a menu option.");

         // Convert the string to a number.
         var IntSelect = parseInt(Selection);

         // Verify the user has provided a number.
         if (isNaN(IntSelect))
         {
            // Display an error dialog.
            alert("Please provide numeric input!");

            // Return without doing anything more.
            return;
         }

         // Call the selection function.
         CheckChoice(IntSelect);
      }
   </script>
</head>

<body>
   <h1>Using the Default Clause</h1>
   <p>Menu Options:</p>
   <ol>
    <li>Item A</li>
    <li>Item B</li>
    <li>Item C</li>
   </ol>
   <input type="button"
          value="Choose a Menu Item"
          onclick="MakeAChoice()" />
   <p id="Result"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a `return` statement in the `if` block. Do you know what [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) does? What about the comment above that statement?

Comment: if `isNaN` runs then `CheckChoice` then becomes unreachable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return in javascript ends a function. If IntSelect is NaN then you will enter a codeblock with a return. Your function then returns before CheckCoice() executes.

Comment: I did not know about that return ends a function in JS. Your answer is comprehensive. Thank you.